# Handle concurrent puppeteer requests through php

Tags: php, node.js, puppeteer, shell-exec

I'm building a web app that retrieves dynamic generated content through puppeteer. I have set up (apache + php) docker containers, one for the p5js project that generates an svg based on a (large, 2MB) json file, and one container with PHP that retrieves that svg. Dockers runs in an Nginx config (nginx for routing, apache for quicker PHP handling). I'm using the cheapest CENTOS server available on digitalocean. So upgrading would definitley help.

I don't want the javascript in the p5js project to be exposed to the public, so I thought a nodejs solution would be best in this scenario.

The PHP page does a `shell_exec("node pup.js")`. It basically runs in approx 1-3 seconds which is perfect.

Problem is when I try to test a multi user scenario and open 5 tabs to run this PHP page, the loadtime drops to even 10+ seconds, which is killing for my app.

So the question would be how to set up this architecture (php calling a node command) for a multi user environment.

===

I've tried several frameworks like [x-ray](https://github.com/matthewmueller/x-ray), [nightmare](https://github.com/segmentio/nightmare#usage), jsdom, cheerio, [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios), [zombie](https://github.com/assaf/zombie), phantom just trying to replace puppeteer. Some of the frameworks returned nothing, some just didn't work out for me. I think I just need a headless browser solution, to be able to execute the p5js. Eventually puppeteer gets the job done, only not in a multi-user environment (I think due to my current php shell_exec puppeteer architecture).

Maybe my shell_exec workflow was the bottleneck, so I ended up building a simple `node example.js` which waits 5 seconds before finish (not using puppeteer), and I ran this with several tabs simultaneously, works like a charm. All tabs load in about 5-6 seconds.

I've also tried `pm2` to test if my node command was the bottleneck, I did some testing on the commandline, with no major results and I couldn't get PHP to run a pm2 command, so I dropped this test.

I've tried setting [PuPHPeteer](https://github.com/nesk/puphpeteer) up, but couldn't get it to run.

At some time I thought it had something to do with multiple puppeteer browsers launched, but I've read that this should be no problem.

The PHP looks like:

```php
<?php
$puppeteer_command = "node /var/www/pup.js >&1";
$result = shell_exec($puppeteer_command);
echo $result;
?>
```

My puppeteer code:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

let url = "http://the-other-dockercontainer/";
let time = Date.now();

let scrape = async () => {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
        args: ['--no-sandbox']
    });
    const page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(url);

    await page.waitForSelector('svg', { timeout: 5000 });
    let svgImage = await page.$('svg');
    await svgImage.screenshot({
        path: `${time}.png`,
        omitBackground: true,
    });

    await browser.close();
    return time;
}

scrape().then((value) => {
    console.log(value); // Success!
});
```

I was thinking about building the entire app in nodejs if that is the best solution, but I've put so many hours in this PHP infrastructure, I'm at the point of really like getting some advice :)

Since I have full control over the target and destination site one brainfart would be to have node to serve a server which accepts a json file and return the svg based on a local p5js site, but don't now (yet) if this would be any different.

**UPDATE**

So thanks to some comments, I've tried a new approach: not using p5js, but native processing code (java). I've exported the processing code to a linux 64bit application and created this little nodejs example:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

var cmd = '/var/www/application.linux64/minimal';
exec(cmd, processing);

// Callback for command line process
function processing(error, stdout, stderr) {

  // I could do some error checking here
  console.log(stdout);

};
```

When I call this node example.js within a shell_exec in PHP, I get this:
[image]

First call takes about 2 seconds. But when I hit a lot of refreshes, time is again building up by a lot of seconds. So, clearly, my understanding of multithreading is not that good, or am I missing something crucial in my testing?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure why you need PHP in this scenario at all. In `nginx` config (I bluntly assumed you're using `nginx`) add a location rule that speaks to node.js instead of PHP for that route. That lets you avoid `shell_exec('node pup.js');`. However, the work here is being done by node.js, so PHP is doing nothing much except acting as a proxy between http request and .js script. From what you described, it appears that all php-fpm children are busy waiting for node.js to finish processing. You can increase the pm.children but it'd appear you're maxing out the resources of your server.

Comment: Well, I started the application because I didn't had that much node experience and needed to use a payment provider which provided a PHP API. I have just tested a simple node example where each request starts a new puppeteer launch. Still a problem with loadtimes adding up. I'm using the cheapest digitalocean server available, so I could experiment with more RAM, but I thought 5 concurrent pages would be no trouble... edit: I've added apache,nginx and digitalocean info to the post.

Comment: The problem is not in handling concurrency, you're screenshotting a page that you have to load first. I don't know why you thought it'd be fast.. You're basically cold-starting an entire (headless) browser, then you're requesting an external page which takes a while on its own, then you're producing a screenshot of that page. On my desktop PC, that action takes a while. If you have 5 requests, each asking puppeteer to screenshot a page - each of the 5 will take up a few seconds. Since you're on the cheapest digitalocean server, that means you've got 1 core CPU. 1 core goes only so far..

Comment: Yes I know. That's why I was wondering if it would be better to not use a headless browser and somehow still execute javascript on a remote site (to be able to generate the svg). But if I'm stuck with a headless browser then I would need more CPU cores (I will test this).

Comment: @Vinzzz I agree with Mjh, the task you are describing is normal to need 10s+. Do you have to use P5.js or could you switch to a library which also works on the server-side?

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I've added an update section. Tried it with native java code that I could run on the server instead of using headless browser.

Comment: @ThomasDondorf I see you're the author of puppeteer-cluster. Can I somehow get in touch with you?

Comment: @Vinzzz Sure, added my mail to my profile

Answer (score 0):

I have a setup similar to you. The biggest problem is your droplet. You should use at minimum the cheapest CPU optimized droplet  ($40 per month from memory). The cheapest generic droplets on DO are in a shared environment (noisy neighbours create performance fluctuations). You can easily test this out by making a snapshot of your server and cloning your drive.

Next as someone else suggested is to reduce the cold starts. On my server a cold start adds around 2 extra seconds. I take 10 screenshots before opening a new browser. Anything more than that and you may run into issues with memory.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to use puppeteer with php you should use make sure you have composer installed then while inside the project folder open terminal windows and type composer require nesk/puphpeteer
also install nesk/rialto, then require autoload everything should work. One thing when working with puppeteer setting const use $ and skip using await command plus replace "." with ->

```
<?php
    require 'vendor/autoload.php';
    use Nesk\Puphpeteer\Puppeteer;
    use Nesk\Rialto\Data\JsFunction;

$puppeteer = new Puppeteer;
$browser = $puppeteer->launch(['headless'=>false,'--proxy-server=000.00.0.0:80']);// Type Proxy

$bot = $browser->newPage();
$data = $bot->evaluate(JsFunction::createWithBody('return document.documentElement.innerHTML'));
$urlPath = $bot->url();

$bot->goto('https://google.com');//goes to google.com
$bot->waitForTimeout(3000);// waits
$bot->type('div', '"cellphonemega"');//searches
$bot->keyboard->press('Enter');//presses enter
$bot->waitForTimeout(8000);//waits
$bot->click('h3', 'https:');//clicks webpage
$bot->waitForTimeout(8000);//waits while site loads
$bot->screenshot(['path' => 'screenshot.png']);// TAKES SCREENSHOT!
$browser->close();//Shuts Down
```

Comment: Mink is also a good alternative